# Trigonometry equation restructuring!

Tags: trigonometry

I would prefer help tonight, if possible, as huge test tomorrow!!!

How do I rewrite this in terms of n?

$$
\frac{4A}{s^2n} = \cot \frac{\pi }{n}
$$

Thank you!!!!

EDIT***: n is always a whole number greater than or equal to 3, as it represents the number of sides of a shape. Also, A and s must both be positive as they represent area and side length.

EDIT 2: Now, I am just looking for the inverse of function $y = x\cot \frac{\pi }{x}$ after using substitution. I would also accept something for $y = x\tan \frac{\pi }{x}$ if that makes any difference

Comment: With difficulty. I strongly doubt there's a nice closed form here.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Remember the famous formula for area of any regular polygon, Area =(1/2)(apothem)(side length)(number of sides)? My precalc honors teacher offered extra credit to anyone who could find eliminate the variable of the apothem and create three equations: one to solve for each variable. S and A were easy; for reference, the equation for area given the side length and number is

Comment: whoops. I posted a little too soon. here is the real comment:

Remember the famous formula for area of any regular polygon, Area =(1/2)(apothem)(side length)(number of sides)? My precalc honors teacher offered extra credit to anyone who could find eliminate the variable of the apothem and create three equations: one to solve for each variable. S and A were easy; for reference, the equation for area given the side length and number is

$$
A = \left ( \frac{s^2n}{4} \right )

\tan \frac{\left ( 
\pi \left ( n-2 \right ) \right )}{2n}
$$

maybe I went wrong somewhere in the derivation?

Comment: i mean the derivation of the equation in the question, not the comment. I had that one checked.

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: Are they any restrictions ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Why do you ask?

Comment: oh you mean on the upper and lower arccotangent bounds, right? my mistake. What would the logical bounds be?

Comment: There is no closed form formula for the (functional) inverse of $y=x\cot(\pi/x)$, nor for $y=x\tan(\pi/x))$.

Comment: why isn't there a formula?

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit solution for this equation in $n$. In order tomake this equation "nicer", you could always rewrite is as $$\tan (x)=\frac{s^2}{4\pi A} x=k x$$ with $x=\frac{\pi}{n}$ and look for solution of $x$ in the range $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$. For sure, there is no solution if $k<1$ except $x=0$.

Ik $k>1$, there is one solution in the considered interval but it needs to be searched by numerical methods such as Newton.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I want to rewrite the equation in terms of n, not find a numberical solution. I'm a bit confused by what you are saying